# Determine callback method, while calling same method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a requirement to call same method for different callbacks. Eg:-

```
after_create :create_feed
after_update :create_feed
after_destroy :create_feed
```

But, inside **create_feed** method, I want to know what callback triggered it (Create or Update or Delete)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

With something like this ?

```
[ :after_create, :after_update, :after_destroy ].each do |callback|
  self.send(callback) { |record| record.create_feed(callback) }
end
```

In other words, it just creates theses lines

```
after_create { |record| record.create_feed(:after_create) }
after_update { |record| record.create_feed(:after_update) }
after_destroy { |record| record.create_feed(:after_destroy) }
```

Comment: Looks straight forward, but don't know why it's going for an infinite loop

Comment: @Abhi you should have a .save or an .update_attributes in your create_feed method.